# Mysql get random username

Tags: php, mysql, random

I need to get a random user name and go to `view.php?name=USERNAME` where am I wrong?

```
<form action="view.php?name=<?php $getname; ?>" method="get">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="RANDOM SKIN" />
</form>
<?php
    include('config.php');
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `skins` ORDER BY rand() limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) {
            $getname = $row2['username'];
            echo $getname;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Who's going to say `Mysql is deprecated` first?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? You haven't marked an answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The form's method is set to GET but you're checking `$_POST`. Either use `method="post"` in the form or `$_GET` in the PHP code.

Comment: I fix it to if ($_GET['submit'])  but its not work ?

Comment: its getting me view.php?submit=RANDOM+SKIN

Comment: If you want to keep the `name` get parameter, you need to use POST.

Comment: Ok i fix it to method="post" and if ($_GET['submit']) and now is view.php?name= ?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the issue of alternating between `$_GET` and `$_POST`, if you want to keep your key value pairs from your GET request, this isn't a big issue. You have multiple options:

**Recommended**

Check out [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). This is available from PHP 4 onward. The documentation has plenty of examples:

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

**Alternative**

Try a `var_dump()` on your `$_SERVER` variables. You should be able to see a `QUERY_STRING` attribute which you can access with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Here, you can manually split your key / values using. Guess what, there's a function for that too!

Check out: [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). You give it a query string, like that from a GET, and it'll sort out all your key values for you. Check out the documentation, it gives you the following example:

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz
```

Pretty simple really! Try both these functions - they're there to solve your exact problem. To get the above working for you, I would first try:

```
var_dump(parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
```

In closing, I'll be the one to talk about MySQL deprecation. Here's what I copy / paste to the newbies:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained, are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and can be [dangerous in live code](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).