# PHP Block submit symbols

Tags: php, submit, block, symbols

how can I block from input **!@#$%^&*()** only **_** and **alphabet** ?
This is my code

```
$query = htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['search']));
$min_length = 3;
if (strlen($query) >= $min_length) {
    $query = htmlspecialchars(trim($query));
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skins WHERE (`username` LIKE '%" . $query . "%')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: "^[a-zA-Z_]*$" should work for if you are allowing upper and lower case

Comment: why have this line  $query = htmlspecialchars(trim($query));, you have already done this before the if?

Comment: You still need to go and **tick an answer correct**: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029234/mysql-get-random-username/20029355#20029355).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['search']));
$min_length = 3;
if (strlen($query) >= $min_length) {
    if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/',$query)){
        $query = htmlspecialchars(trim($query));
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skins WHERE (`username` LIKE '%" . $query . "%')") or die(mysql_error());
    } else {
        //do something if $query contains something else than alphanumeric and _ chars
    }
}
```